# How to find Flow of Funds and Money Trail in Python for Finance

Tags: programming, quantlib, quantitative

**I'm trying to find Flow of Funds and Money Trail using python**

**but i'm stuck in middle of it not understanding what to do next**

**My Main goal is to finding Flow of Funds i.e flow of transaction from one account to another**

**Or there is any library that will be helpful  ?**

*data.csv file*

[image: data.csv file]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('fof_dataset/Data_set.csv').fillna('0')
df["Debit"] = df["Debit"].str.replace(",","").astype(int)
df["Credit"] = df["Credit"].str.replace(",","").astype(int)
df["Balance"] = df["Balance"].str.replace(",","").astype(int)

df['tail'] = df['Debit']-df['Balance']
df['tail_1']=df['tail']+df['Balance']
df
#df.loc[df['Debit']  == 0, 'name_match'] = 'Null_value'  
#df.loc[df['Debit']   > 0, 'name_match'] = 'Value'

# df['name_match'] = df['Debit'].apply(lambda x: 'Value' if x > 0 else 'Null')
# df
```

**Example [Output should be like]**

**B-->A-->C (this is one Flow of Fund Record)**

**X-->A-->D-->E-->H  (so on...)**

Comment: If you are asking how to write programs to help in Money Laundering investigations, it would seem to be outside the scope of QuantFinance. It is purely a programming question involving Python and Graph Theory (finding paths though a graph).

Comment: @noob2 yeah ! something like that.. You know any library that will help me or I could make use of it

Comment: @Assassin some helpful libraries off the top of my may be `graphviz`: https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/ or `networkx`: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/